# Summation of variables by Groups in R

Tags: r, grouping, stata

I have a data frame, and I'd like to create a new column that gives the sum of a numeric variable grouped by factors.  So something like this:

BEFORE:

```
data1 <- data.frame(month = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
                    sex = c("m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "f"), 
                    value = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60))
```

AFTER:

```
data2 <- data.frame(month = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
                    sex = c("m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "f"), 
                    value = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60), 
                    sum = c(30, 30, 70, 70, 110, 110))
```

In Stata you can do this with the `egen` command quite easily.  I've tried the aggregate function, and the ddply function but they create entirely new data frames, and I just want to add a column to the existing one.

Comment: what are you trying to sum? its not obvious by the way you're asking the question. try tapply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `ave`

```
> data2 <- transform(data1, sum=ave(value, month, FUN=sum))
  month sex value sum
1     1   m    10  30
2     1   f    20  30
3     2   m    30  70
4     2   f    40  70
5     3   m    50 110
6     3   f    60 110
```

`data1$sum <- ave(data1$value, data1$month, FUN=sum)` is useful if you don't want to use `transform`

Also `data.table` is helpful

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(data1)
DT[, sum:=sum(value), by=month]
```

***UPDATE***

We can also use a `tidyverse` approach which is simple, yet elegant:

```
> library(tidyverse)
> data1 %>% 
    group_by(month) %>% 
    mutate(sum=sum(value))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   month [3]
  month sex   value   sum
  <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 m        10    30
2     1 f        20    30
3     2 m        30    70
4     2 f        40    70
5     3 m        50   110
6     3 f        60   110
```